# Computed Column is too slow in ordering or filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a computed column I use for ordering or filtering, but when there is 1000+ rows it takes too long to execute.

This query is for a booking system to order the Available Dates depending on their prices.

Here is database schema:

```
AvailableDates has one DateGroup
DateGroup has many Prices
DateGroup has many Discounts
Each Discount contains 3 columns. MinPerson, MaxPerson, DiscountPercentage
AvailableDates has many BookingGroups.
BookingGroups has many Bookings.
BookingGroups has a computed column that calculates how many bookings there are.
```

The computed column for price on AvailableDate is computed by a function. Price is determined with;

```
Get Max Price from Prices
Get How many booking there is
Get discount that will be applied depending on number of bookings.
```

Here is the function query:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_datePrice]
    (
      @id INT,
      @groupId INT
    )
RETURNS decimal(19, 5)
AS
    BEGIN
    declare @price decimal(19,5), @discount decimal(19,5), @numOfPeople INT
    SELECT @numOfPeople= b.NumberOfPeople FROM BookingGroup b
                WHERE b.DateId = @id and b.Status != 'Expired';

    if (@numOfPeople is null or @numOfPeople < 1)
        SET @numOfPeople = 1;

    SELECT @price = MAX(pr.Price),
        @discount = disc.DiscountPercentage
    FROM DateGroup dateGroup
    LEFT JOIN Prices pr on pr.GroupId = dateGroup.Id
    LEFT JOIN Discounts disc on disc.GroupId = dateGroup.Id and @numOfPeople BETWEEN disc.MinPeople and disc.MaxPeople
    WHERE dateGroup.Id = @groupId
    GROUP BY dateGroup.Id, disc.DiscountPercentage;

    if (@discount is null)
        return @price
    return @price * (100 - @discount) / 100
    END;
GO
```

Execution Plan says 78% of the cost is on: Key Lookup (Clustered) [AvailableDate].[PK_AvailableDate]

My activity monitor says this query is the most expensive one:

```
SELECT @price = MAX(pr.Price),
            @discount = disc.DiscountPercentage
        FROM DateGroup dateGroup
        LEFT JOIN Prices pr on pr.GroupId = dateGroup.Id
        LEFT JOIN Discounts disc on disc.GroupId = dateGroup.Id and @numOfPeople BETWEEN disc.MinPeople and disc.MaxPeople
        WHERE dateGroup.Id = @groupId
        GROUP BY dateGroup.Id, disc.DiscountPercentage;
```

Comment: `Execution Plan says 78% of the cost is on: Key Lookup (Clustered) [Date].[PK_Date]` please share execution plan as xml

Comment: What is [Date]?  I do not see any [Date].  I only see a [DateGroup].

Comment: Is coverting the scalar function to a table valued function an option? Generally TVF (in-line TVF preferably) is faster then it's scalar counterpart.

Comment: [Date] is [AvailableDates] Table I'll edit the question to show it properly.

Comment: @Serg I will check that out and see if that is an option for me. I was also thinking about triggers to update that column when one of the related columns change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this help you understand the computed columns? 
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_nevarez/archive/2009/08/10/the-query-optimizer-and-computed-columns.aspx

If DB size and write times are not issues, I would consider to denormalise the schema. That would remove the need for a function to compute at the cost of write times. For example, the dategroup x price x discount could be in one table. The table can be unique & clustered indexed by dategroupid for look up.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too but the problem is the price still differs depending on how many booking there are.

Comment: While re-writing the function like 'Prabhat G' recommended helped the speed, it is still not fast enough. Therefore, after speaking with the client we have decided the change the schema and denormalise it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to re-write your join :

```
SELECT @price = MAX(pr.Price),
            @discount = disc.DiscountPercentage
FROM DateGroup dateGroup
LEFT JOIN Prices pr on pr.GroupId = dateGroup.Id
LEFT JOIN Discounts disc on disc.GroupId = dateGroup.Id 
WHERE   (@numOfPeople BETWEEN disc.MinPeople and disc.MaxPeople)
        AND (dateGroup.Id = @groupId)
GROUP BY dateGroup.Id, disc.DiscountPercentage;
```

try and let me know if it makes impact.

Comment: This sped up my query a lot (Nearly double). But still not fast enough. Down to 1:05 from 1:59

Comment: Good. Another thing is `parameter sniffing`. I don't know if it will actually make impact. It impacts stored procedures alot. All you need to do is declare  @id1, @group1 as input parameters and inside begin set them to @id, @group respectively

Answer (score 0):

Always you can try to rewrite this function to inline, you need to remember that multiline-functions are alwyas much slower than inline-functions.